# Smarty - include template and update an existing variable

Tags: php, html, smarty

I've recently started working with Smarty and I'm trying to find my way around. Here's what I don't know in the very moment:

I'm including a file:

```
{include file="nforum/_partials/box_forum.tpl"}
```

In that file, I have this:

```
<a href="{$t->link}">{$t->title|truncate:$link_truncate}</a>
```

I would like to pass $link_truncate a value of 30 while including the template (not inside the box_forum.tpl - that's important to me!)

I'm trying with:

```
{include file="nforum/_partials/box_forum.tpl" $link_truncate = 30}
```

without success. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare, before include the template:

```
{assign var="link_truncate" value="30"}
```

Comment: Now we're talking! Thnx!