# Smarty - pass variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty

I've recently asked a question on how to pass a variable in Smarty: [Smarty - include template and update an existing variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753563/smarty-include-template-and-update-an-existing-variable)

It's working fine for me, but now I need something a little more advanced from what I see.

In one template I attach a gallery slider template as a variable:

```
{$gallery_slider}
```

In the gallery template (which is a general file for other pages, so I don't want to change it) there's the jQuery slider with options. I would like to change the number of visible slides. For now it looks like this:

```
visible :   {$partial.visible|default:5},
```

If I change default to 3 in the template, it works, but I would like to do this from the level of the template that calls the gallery - above {$gallery_slider}.

How do I do that? I've tried:

```
{assign var="partial.visible" value="3"}
```

and

```
{assign var="partial.visible|default:3"}
```

and some other combinations, none of them works.

I'd appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you used this as variable (probably `fetch` method) but you should rather use `include` in this case:

```
{include file="gallery.tpl" items=5}

{include file="gallery.tpl" items=3}
```

and now if in `gallery.tpl` you have:

```
Here I can display {$items} in my gallery<br />
```

output will be:

```
Here I can display 5 in my gallery
Here I can display 3 in my gallery
```

so you can use this variable and in loop (or other control structure) use this variable without any problem

Comment: Thnx, I'll remember about that in the future. Anyway, I'm not allowed to change the method (it's been like that since ever and this is how they want it), so it doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @oneday, so show how you create this variable and what you can change. If you cannot modify anything or change how you create this variable, you won't be able to pass any paramters

Comment: I don't see the code that creates the variable (it's not my part of the job), but I managed to achieve the desired effect via CSS alone. The slider is set to 5 images per row, but only slides 3 of them, so I made each of the images equal 1/3 of the slider area and now I only see 3 and slide 3, which is ok for me.